# Three20: unreconized selector when adding TTActivityLabel like in the sample

Tags: three20

I add an TTActivityLabel, pretty much like in the sample:

```
    TTActivityLabel *label = [[[TTActivityLabel alloc] initWithStyle:TTActivityLabelStyleBlackBezel] autorelease];
    label.text = @"Hello World.";
    [label sizeToFit];
    label.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, myView.width, label.height);
    [myView addSubview:label];
```

The code crashes on -sizeToFit with:

```
2010-02-09 14:42:21.065 MIB[17092:207] *** -[UICFFont ttLineHeight]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xf15e30
```

I already figured out, that ttLineHeight is an addition to UIFont, that seems to not be correctly identified by Xcode. How can this happen? Maybe i do something wrong when importing Three20?

When i run the debugger, it interrupts inside the code of TTActivityLabel where the error happens. I am not sure if this is the correct behaviour. Maybe it should not break inside TT code, since this is a static library?

Any help is appreciated =)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Alright, i found the solution.

There was indeed an error made by me when i added the three20 libraries to my project.

"Other linker flags" in build settings was not set to "-all_load -ObjC". I fixed that and now it works fine.